# How to write subscript text in python?

Tags: python, formatting, subscript

I am trying to write a text subscript in python, but all i can find is subscript letters. The text I need to show as a subscript is "A,B". So my final product should be: Text subscript(A,B). I tried the $Text{A,B}$ but when i include the comma (,) this does not work anymore. Any one has an idea?
Thank you

Comment: Can you show us exactly what you are doing?

Comment: oh i figured out that ax1.set_xlabel("$f_{A,B}$") would work. However, the font is italic. is there a way to make it normal font? Thanks.